# The monit of docker?

Tags: docker

I'm switching over to docker. Would like to do something like monit: if a container crash, restart it. if memory goes above a certain limit, restart it. How could it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the Container Restart feature provided by docker give some help, it's not as thorough as monit. I asked around on fig repo https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/464 and it was suggested to use God or Bluepill. I looked at God and it makes a lot of sense running God in the container and have God monitor the webapp process for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Docker's 1.2 new feature: `Container Restart`. It might not be as powerful as monit though (I can't tell as I don't know the tool).

You can add the flag `--restart=always` to `docker run` to tell docker to always restart the container when it crashes.

Concerning the memory limit case, you can monitor the container from the outside by fetching logs created by a monitoring tool inside the container and restart it using `docker restart` with a simple script. Or if you have your own program running, you could code it so that it exits with a meaningful exit code when it reaches memory limit and restart the container with `--restart=on-failure:<number-of-tries>`.

For further information you can look at the Docker 1.2 [release note](https://blog.docker.com/2014/08/announcing-docker-1-2-0/)